# Not able to update and delete data from mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using ejs template, expressjs, and mongoose. not able to update existed data through form while click on edit button and as well not able to delete it . I want to delete when user click a button as well when user click on edit button it show form and allow him to edit. I already wrote get route , it is working fine.

```
**Update route:**

router.put('/success123' , function (req, res) {
  // const id = req.params.id;

  Campaign.findById(id)
      .then(campaign => {

          campaign.Title = req.body.title;

          campaign.Description = req.body.Description;

          campaign.save().then(updatePost => {

              res.render('success123');

          });
      });

});

**Delete route**

router.delete  ('/delete/:id' , function (req, res){

  Campaign.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
      .then(deletedPost => {

          res.render('success');
      });
});
```

I am getting error and cant figure it out . Event it is not showing any error message in my console. both deleting and updating parts not working and i am able to success fully get route while user click on edit campaign button.

**My ejs template for update :** THIS IS MY EJS TEMPALTE WHERE I AM SENDING UPDATE INFORMATION THROUGH FORM

```
<div class="row p-4">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <form action="/success123" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" value="<%=camplist.Title%>" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Enter The Title">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description">Description</label>
                    <textarea value="" name="description" id="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your content here" rows="10"><%=camplist.Description%></textarea>
                </div>
        <div>
                <input  class="form-control" name="rules" type="hidden" placeholder="Enter The Title">
                <textarea name="rules" id="editor"></textarea>

            </textarea>
           </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="file">Upload Your Banner Image </label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="uploadedFile"  accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/bmp">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" type="submit">Update Post</button>

            </form>
```

I am getting error and cant figure it out . Event it is not showing any error message in my console. both deleting and updating parts not working and i am able to success fully get route while user click on edit campaign button.

Comment: Is there any errors are you facing ?

Comment: 404 error are occured

Comment: Please provide error logs, as per me it should be from the body of the request and the field mismatching with the original schema

Comment: Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "

Comment: as expected. the template is not found by the server. please try to check your template names and relevant path in accordance with the server file.

Comment: I checked and every thing is fine

Comment: Please try to check again, because as per the error it is related to path issue

Comment: Not able figure out , every thing looking fine . Can you view my above code once